# iPhone App Icon - usage and licensing

Tags: iphone, licensing, icons, itunesartwork

I hope this is the right place to post this. If not, please redirect and I will be happy to move.

I am a little confused about the App Icon that represents our app in iTunes and on the devices. I am having some questions, specifically, about licensing for the icons I choose to use.

Technically, I was wondering of the app icon is officially defined as a 'logo'. It seems like if it is called a logo, on many sites you have to buy the exclusive rights to an image before using it as an app icon.

Otherwise, it seems like you can simply purchase an extended license. Obviously this differs from site to site, but they seem to all say I need a simple extended license when I describe the use, then they turn around and say that a logo needs exclusive rights. It's too bad that mant of these sites haven't addressed iOS applications as a category specifically.

Additionally, we specify several icon images within our apps in the plist file. I think I read somewhere that we might need a separate license for each of these icons, even if the same image is used repeatedly.

I could really use some feedback on this issue. I want to be compliant with the law and respect the needed licenses, without spending way more than I need to, and I already have app icons out there (and can't get a consistent answer from the site where I bought the icons) so I don't want to go the paid designer route. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think that there *is* an appropriate Stack Exchange site for this question, but as your question seems reducible to: "I want to be compliant with the law and respect the needed licenses," the only answer I can offer is "consult an appropriately qualified lawyer for the country/jurisdiction in which you're publishing."

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, ***we are not lawyers. We cannot give you legal advice.***

That said, you should not use art you do not own in your app, regardless of how you use it. As an app icon, it may well count as a logo depending on the legal/applicable definition of that term. It certainly counts as copyright infringement if you don't have the rights to the art in question.

Ideally, the company you're working with should be supplying the app icon and other art. If they're unable to do that, they don't sound terribly professional. Art is not (usually) the coder's responsibility. Check with the company and *get* a consistent answer.

Comment: I don't work with a company. I'm a stay at home mom : ) I buy my artwork off of sites that license artwork/icons. Most of them just have not put together a specific written policy for iPhone apps and which license they require. It would be good to ask a lawyer if I had one. I was just hoping someone else had used these sites and could let me know what they found. Thanks for your input.

Comment: You stated "and can't get a consistent answer from my company!" Did you mean the company that produced the artwork?

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry about the confusion. I see now why you said that about the company. I'll edit to correct.

Answer (score 0):

As Jonathan said so well above, I am not a lawyer, so take this with a grain of salt... it is not legal advice.

Whether or not an image can be used with an extended license, without full-on purchasing the rights, seems to depend on it is technically a *logo* or not. Also, whether you are trademarking the image. The logo part is where things get grey... and I haven't been able to find any clear answer on it. There may not BE a clear answer.